# Kotlin - Usefulness of "computed" var properties?

Tags: kotlin

I noticed that when I have a `var` property with a custom `get`, that does not use the `field` identifier, a backing field is generated anyway. I checked the bytecode, and the documentation says so as well:

> A backing field will be generated for a property if it uses the
>   default implementation of **at least one of the accessors**, or if a
>   custom accessor references it through the field identifier.
>   (emphasis is mine)

Consider a class like this. Since it's a `var` property, a default `set` (and therefore a backing field) will be generated:

```
class Banana {
    var ripeness = 1

    var color: String = "green"
        get() = when {
            ripeness > 80 -> "brown"
            ripeness > 50 -> "yellow"
            else -> "green"
        }
}

val b = Banana()
b.color = "blue"

println(b.color)
```

However, the `println` will always print "green", no matter what I set `color` to. The backing field will be set to "blue" anyway.
Since there is no way to access it outside the accessor methods (or via reflection) I really can't think of a reason for this.
Am I missing something here? Maybe a usecase or another way of accessing the backing field? Or is it just a bug (or a missing warning in IntelliJ)?

Comment: The use case is that you may want to use the backing field inside the custom getter. Not doing so makes the backing field useless. I think this should have given a compiler warning.

Comment: @marstran yes I agree with the warning. It's an edge case, but one you can quickly run into, so I thought there might be more to it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A "computed" *`var`* property with an unused backing field should be a "computed" *`val`* property.

If you are not going to use the backing field in your example then `Banana.color` shouldn't be a `var` but a `val`. e.g.:

```
class Banana {
    var ripeness = 1

    val color: String
        get() = when {
            ripeness > 80 -> "brown"
            ripeness > 50 -> "yellow"
            else -> "green"
        }
}
```

On the other hand, if you actually wanted to make your "computed" property overridable in some cases then you would need to actually use the backing field. e.g.:

```
class Banana {
    var ripeness = 1

    var color: String = "green"
        get() = when {
            ripeness > 80 -> "brown"
            ripeness > 50 -> "yellow"
            else -> field
        }
}
```

Comment: Yes,I know that I should declare it `val`. I just thought it's a trap that especially beginners might easily run into, and therefore thought that there might be a good reason to allow it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Beware of val ... get(), the behavior migth be very surprising:

```
class Val {
    val millis: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
}
class ValGet {
    val millis: Long
        get() = System.currentTimeMillis()
}

val v = Val()
val g = ValGet()
for(i in 0..4) {
    println("val:" +  v.millis + " valget:"+g.millis)
    Thread.sleep(7)
}
```

What's the use of `val` if a `val x: Int` cannot be relied upon to be the same when referenced twice? Apparently it even works for overrides if the parent is sufficiently open, an `abstract val looksQuiteLikeImmutable : Int` can be very misleading. Feels like groovy all over again... (At least this is what I observe in 1.4.21)

Comment: well, `millis` a property of the object, `val` indicates that *users of the object* can't change it. but users should not expect that it doesn't change. however, in this particular case, a function would probably make more sense than a property, as the system millis are not a property of any object... except the system...

Comment: ...and that can be very misleading, because  to the uninitiated, `val somthing:Int` certainly doesn't look like describing a _function return type_. The `get()` effectively becomes part of the type, but convention puts it on a separate line and there is zero indication on the first line that the type isn't completely specified yet. Definitely a "beware of" pitfall in my eyes. Tools like IntelliJ (they should know a thing or two about kotlin) present them all the same at the usage site (including the actual equivalent of a Java `final long something;`, a val defined in the default constructor).